# Bitmask for converting letters to uppercase

Tags: bit, bitmask, lc3

I can't seem to figure out a bitmask for converting both upper case and lower case letters to upper case. I know I can use XOR 00100000 for converting lowercase to uppercase but this would not work if I XOR an upper case letter with 00100000 back to the same upper case letter. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are mistaken, the XOR works the same in both directions.

Comment: Of course you must confirm that the character is a letter before you apply the XOR.

Comment: Hmm correct me if I'm wrong but when I try to convert 'A' (01000001) back to 'A' (01000001) itself by XOR-ing 00100000 it becomes 01100001 ('a'). Is there any way in which I can use one bitmask that is capable of converting any lowercase letter to uppercase like 'a' to 'A' and 'A' to 'A' (an uppercase letter back to itself)?

Comment: No, that's not how XOR works.  I think you're looking for AND.  And you'll still want to make sure the character is a letter before you do this.